# Embed Jetty in Eclipse RCP

Tags: proxy, jetty, eclipse-rcp

I am building a RCP application , where I need to monitor http traffic and show it to user. For that I require use of Embeded Jetty as transparent proxy.

I tried everything , followed this [Tutorial](http://blog.firdau.si/2009/11/06/embedding-jetty-server-in-eclipse-rcp/) But things just don't work. I get build exception. 
I tried adding Jetty jar as external dependency , but still no use.

Would appreciate any help. Also please let me know if there are any other ways of achieving this without use of jetty. (I tried Socks but it conflicts with RCP UI thread)
Thank You.

Comment: Improving the description of the error message you get and the steps you follow to get it might rise the probability of somebody providing a correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In broad terms you need to look into making eclipse plugins and how to declare dependencies in eclipse plugin projects.  What you are basically looking to do is write a bit of code based on our jetty embedded examples only in a plugin context, so when your plugin loads it would trigger the starting of the jetty server.  You will load the jetty dependencies as osgi bundles. Note that in juno much of jetty 8.1.3 will be available by default.

Its not the best example in the world, but you can look at our crusty wtp plugin for some ideas, at least on how you could configure things using tycho and maybe some organizational bits.

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.wtp.git/